# Ansible - how to execute on a host a specif yaml file on role

Tags: ansible

I have a ansible playbook

```
mainly.yml - roles - roles1 - tasks - main.yml
                                    playbook1.yml
                                    playbook2.yml   
                 - roles2 - tasks - main.yml
                                    playbook3.yml
                                    playbook4.yml
```

```
main.yml on roles1
- name: install
  import_tasks:"playbook1.yml"
  tags:
    - role_install
    - role_install_configure

- name: configure
  import_tasks:"playbook2.yml"
  tags:
    - role_configure
    - role_install_configure
```

on playbook1.yml, I want to execute on a specific hostname server, when I use the tag role_install_configure to trigger the both role on mainly.yml

$ cat playbook1.yml

```
- name: copy
  copy:...

- name: command
  command:...

- name: copy
  templates:...
```

So, I want to excute on whole playbook1.yml to only one hostname and playbook1.yml  and playbook2.yml with default host on inventory on mainly.yml

I know that I can use when: ansible_host == "server1"

but, I want a simply way to use it, because if I have 10 instructions, I have to use 10 times the ansible_host, it would be not interesting.

maybe someting like that :

```
- hosts: server1

- name: copy
  copy:...

- name: command
  command:...

- name: copy
  templates:...
```

I don't want to use cli ansible to use a specific host, I want the instruction on yaml file

like that only one instruction it would work.

Maybe I have to use import_role and import_taks on mainly.yml, but I want to trigger that with the tag role_install_configure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the module [import_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_role_module.html) and ask for a particular file with the tasks. For example, create a project

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── pb1.yml
└── roles
    ├── role1
    │   └── tasks
    │       ├── play1.yml
    │       └── play2.yml
    └── role2
        └── tasks
            ├── play3.yml
            └── play4.yml
```

The file

```yaml
shell> cat roles/role1/tasks/play1.yml 
- debug:
    msg: copy
- debug:
    msg: command
- debug:
    msg: template
```

and the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: test_01

  tasks:

    - import_role:
        name: role1
        tasks_from: play1
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
PLAY [test_01] ******************************************************************************

TASK [role1 : debug] ************************************************************************
ok: [test_01] => 
  msg: copy

TASK [role1 : debug] ************************************************************************
ok: [test_01] => 
  msg: command

TASK [role1 : debug] ************************************************************************
ok: [test_01] => 
  msg: template
```

Comment: thank u very much, I update my question because is not exactly that I want, anayway thank for your answer ;)

Comment: @esefesgrgrz As far as I understood your question, [Vladimir Botka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6482561/vladimir-botka)'s answer seems to be exactly what you need. Reading the question again gives me a feeling that you are confusing playbooks with roles, so below is a quick reminder of how Ansible works: 1) Playbooks consist of plays. Plays run on hosts or groups of hosts. 2)  Plays may consist of tasks and/or role invocations. 3) Roles consist of tasks. Roles are **not** related to hosts or groups. 4) Tasks are the smallest instruction unit. Tasks are **not** related to hosts or groups.

Comment: You added that you want to run that task using a tag - that's not a problem, playbooks support tags for both tasks and roles

Comment: I added what ? I don't understand, which section ?

Comment: I mean in the last sentence of your question you said _I want to trigger that with the tag `role_install_configure`_